# Factoring a trinomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm given the trinomial $y^3-8y^2+16y-4 = 0$. How can I factor this? 
I know that this can be written as:
$(y-a) (y-b) (y-c)$, where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are the roots of the equations. Expanding this and comparing the terms, we get that:
$a+b+c = 8$;
$ab+ac+bc = 16$;
$abc = 4$
Is there a way to find the sum of the roots?

Comment: sum of roots is just $a+b+c.$

Comment: that's a quadrinomial not a trinomial.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Rational Root Theorem](http://www.mathwords.com/r/rational_root_theorem.htm) to quickly notice that there are no rational roots. So there's really no nice way to factor this. In fact, [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%5E3+-+8y%5E2+%2B+16y+-+4+%3D+0) even confirms this.

Comment: hey, my bad but I wrote the wrong equation, it's not +4, it's -4.

Comment: @user201254 OK, but the same comment holds. :)